How to use LWC to capture opportunity data and create new opportunity with modified data
I am using Quick Action on Opportunity record to create an LWC to edit Opportunity record and create a new record. I am unable to display the data on template.Here is my JS of Record Edit Form LWC
import { LightningElement, api,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from "lightning/actions";
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getDetailsforRamp from '@salesforce/apex/FieldSetController.getDetailsforRamp';

export default class CreateRampButton extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    opportunityRecord;
    @track isvalid ;
    isLoading = true;
    isDataLoaded=true;
    error;
    fields = [];
    connectedCallback() {
        this.objectApiName = 'Opportunity';
        this.isLoading = true;

        let decodedDef = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.substring(1));
        let cmpDef;
        if(decodedDef){
            cmpDef = JSON.parse(atob(decodedDef));
            this.recordId = cmpDef.state.c__recordId;
        }
        getDetailsforRamp({ oppId: this.recordId })
            .then(result => {
                
                this.opportunityRecord = result;
             
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error retrieving fields: ', error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.isLoading = false; // Hide spinner when loading is complete
            });
    }
    renderedCallback(){
        
        if (this.isDataLoaded) {
        if (this.opportunityRecord) {
            const inputfields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
            inputfields.forEach(field => {

             //   if(field.fieldName === "Amount"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.Amount;
                if(field.fieldName === "Name"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.Name + ' - Ramp';
            }
                if(field.fieldName === "AccountId"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.AccountId.Name;
                }
                
                if(field.fieldName === "Type"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.Type;
                }
                if(field.fieldName === "RecordTypeId"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.RecordTypeId;
                }
                if(field.fieldName === "LeadSource"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.LeadSource;
                }
                if(field.fieldName === "StageName"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.StageName;
                }
                if(field.fieldName === "Probability"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.Probability;
                }
                if(field.fieldName === "CloseDate"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.CloseDate;
                }
                if(field.fieldName === "ForecastCategoryName"){field.value = this.opportunityRecord.ForecastCategoryName;
            }
            });
        }
    }
    }
    
    saveClick(event) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.isvalid = true;
        const inputfields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
        inputfields.forEach(field => {
            if(field.required && field.value == null){
                this.isvalid= false;
            }
        });
        if(this.isvalid){
            const inputFields = event.detail.fields;
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(inputFields);
        }else{
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
        
    }

    closemodel(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }
 
    handleSuccess(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.isLoading = false; // Set to false to hide the spinner when loading is complete
        }, 2000);
        const labrecordId = event.detail.id;
        console.log('::::::::',event.detail.id);
        // Navigate to the record page
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: labrecordId,
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
        
    }
}

<template>
    <lightning-card title="New Opportunity ">
        <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={objectApiName} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
             
       <lightning-accordion>
            <lightning-accordion-section name="Opportunity Information" label="Opportunity Information">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" ></lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Type"></lightning-input-field>
                           <lightning-input-field field-name="RecordTypeId"></lightning-input-field>
                             <lightning-input-field field-name="LeadSource"></lightning-input-field>
                                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="CloseDate"></lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="StageName" ></lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Probability" ></lightning-input-field>
                                      </div>
    
                    
                </div>
                                
                </lightning-accordion-section>
                  <lightning-button variant="brand" slot="actions" onclick={handleSave}>Save</lightning-button>
                   <lightning-button variant="neutral" slot="actions" onclick={handleCancel}>Cancel</lightning-button>
    
    
                            </lightning-accordion> 
                      
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
       </lightning-card>
</template>

The class for getting data is as per below
public class FieldSetController {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) 
    public static Opportunity getDetailsforRamp(ID oppId){ 
        opportunity opp = [SELECT Id,name,AccountId,Closedate,type,stagename,Probability,ForecastCategoryName,LeadSource,RecordTypeId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId]; 
        return opp; 
    }
}


Add error details/screenshot if possible.

Error is not coming but in UI values are not populating. Here are the console values
Record Id in navigation: 0067F000004hcX2QAI
createRampButton.js:1
opportunityRecord::::::
ObjectAccountId: "0017F00000NQXHbQAP"
CloseDate: "2018-12-07"    ForecastCategoryName: "Pipeline" Id: "0067F000004hcX2QAI"Name: "500 units"Probability: 10RecordTypeId: "0127F000000IT00QAG"StageName: "Prospecting"Type: "New Customer"[[Prototype]]: Object

After reviewing your code, what i have understood is.... you are trying to show a form with modified values of an existing opportunity and planning to save it as another opportunity record. If yes, to copy existing opt record values first try to use onload event method of form. The save button does not have submit type how would you expect to create it. Code looks unclear..
